# Google Analytics DataChart - how do I create a single line chart with multiple series?

Tags: google-analytics, google-visualization

I have 3 different types of events that I track. I want to display a single line chart for all these events showing the event count per day - so there should be 3 data series in the chart, one series for each different eventLabel. However, the DataChart complains if I try to pass `'dimensions': 'ga:date,ga:eventLabel'` - it gives me error: "All series on a given axis must be of the same data type".

So, I have reverted to displaying all the charts as 3 separate line graphs. How do I combine these into 1, with different color lines for each different eventLabel?

```js
  for (var i = 0; i < eventLabels.length; ++i) {
    var chart1 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
      query: {
        'ids': myID,
        'start-date': '30daysAgo',
        'end-date': 'today',
        'metrics': 'ga:totalEvents',
        'dimensions': 'ga:date',
        'filters': baseFilters + ";ga:eventLabel==" + eventLabel[i]
      },
      chart: {
        'container': 'chart-' + i + '-container',
        'type': 'LINE',
        'options': {
          'width': '100%'
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

[image: 3 charts]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart` is able to take only one query object. So it is not possible to achieve what you are looking for using that.

You have to create three `gapi.analytics.report.Data` (one for each of your eventLabels) and then tie them together using a `google.visualization.data.join` and finally use that to create a line chart by using `google.visualization.LineChart`.

I have tried and tested the following code and it works. (It needs different libraries - charts loader and jsapi).

```
var data1 = new gapi.analytics.report.Data({
    query: {
        'ids': yourId,
        'dimensions': 'ga:date',
        'metrics': 'ga:totalEvents',
        'start-date': '30daysAgo',
        'end-date': 'yesterday',
        'filters': 'ga:eventLabel==' + eventLabel[0],
        'output': 'dataTable'
    }
});

var data2 = new gapi.analytics.report.Data({
    query: {
        'ids': yourId,
        'dimensions': 'ga:date',
        'metrics': 'ga:totalEvents',
        'start-date': '30daysAgo',
        'end-date': 'yesterday',
        'filters': 'ga:eventLabel==' + eventLabel[1],
        'output': 'dataTable'
    }
});

data1.on('success', function(response1) {
    var table1 = new google.visualization.DataTable(response1.dataTable);
    data2.execute();
    data2.on('success', function(response2) {
        var table2 = new google.visualization.DataTable(response2.dataTable);
        var dataFinal = google.visualization.data.join(table1, table2, 'full', [[0,0]],[1],[1]);
        dataFinal.setColumnLabel(1, eventLabel[0]);
        dataFinal.setColumnLabel(2, eventLabel[1]);
        chart.draw(dataFinal, {'interpolateNulls': true});
        chart.draw(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(response2.rows));
    });
});


data1.execute();
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('timeline'));
```

Hope this solves your problem.